# Grid/List view  with image size

Tags: php, javascript, list, grid

I have problem with change images size in posts (after click on the buttons grid/list).

these are the buttons that should (after click) change $value to true or false (that scale images):

```
<div class="products_look">
        <input type="button" class="view_list" onclick="" value="List" />
        <input type="button" class="view_grid" onclick="" value="Grid" />
</div>
```

and this is the php functions that generated grid or list view in the posts:

```
<?php
    if($value == true) {
      echo image_products_grid();
    }
    else {
      echo image_products_list();
    }
?>
```

What I need to insert in onClick tags that after clicking on the button returned php $value (true or false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a parameter in the URL? Something like this:

```
<div class="products_look">
    <input type="button" class="view_list" onclick="window.location = 'display.php?type=LIST'" value="List" />
    <input type="button" class="view_grid" onclick="window.location = 'display.php?type=GRID'" value="Grid" />
</div>
```

And then on your PHP page:

```
<?php
    if($_GET["type"] == "GRID") {
      echo image_products_grid();
    }
    else {
      echo image_products_list();
    }
?>
```

Is this the type of solution that you are looking for? It's not terribly elegant, but your question is a little unclear so I hope this helps.

Comment: I do not believe that it was so easy.

It can be done without a page refresh? because to these html tags 'a' is assigned JS function (that changes the css).

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you are asking... Are you asking whether or not this can be done without a page refresh? If so, the only way that I know of for you to get a response from a server without reloading the entire page would be to use AJAX. There's a good, simple example here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp